# How can I create a Tag?

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, tags

Is the reason that I cannot see that functionality that I have too low reputation?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need 1500 reputation now to create new tags.

There are 55,000 tags already available (at time of writing).  Odds are what you need is included among their number.

Keep in mind that many seemingly obvious tags may be named different than you expect, to avoid ambiguity. For example, `access` seems like it should be an obvious tag. However, it is not used because it was often attached to questions covering both security permissions and a certain notorious database platform. Instead, the tags `authorization` or `permissions` should be used for the former, and `ms-access` for the latter. These names avoid ambiguity, and there is zero additional benefit to also using "access" in either case.

Also remember that the point of tags on Stack Exchange is not to summarize your question, but rather to sort it into a set of well-defined categories. Tags are how your question connects to an audience of users qualified to answer it. These users will have certain tags marked as 'interesting' or subscribe to the rss feeds for their tags. If you create a new tag, that tag is guaranteed to not help attract any of those users.

A good rule of thumb is to check the auto-suggest prompts when tagging your question. Any tag with a number less than 10 (100 on Stack Oveflow itself) after it's name is more than likely wrong. If you feel you have a fairly common topic (take 'mssql' for example) and you see a very small number for that tag, try an alternate name (like 'sql-server').

Comment: Double check number? FAQ says 250

Comment: The UV item was closed saying 200- hopefully the FAQ is right, but I have no way to know for sure.

Comment: It has changed I believe, I got a message that **users with less than 1500 reputation can't create new tags.** and this page also says the same: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags

Comment: How do I put a description for the new tag?

Answer (score 23):

You "create" a tag simply by using it on a post. If it doesn't let you, you don't have enough rep (you need 250 on SO; 100 on SF and MSO - if the FAQs are up to date...).

Comment: This was recently (as in just today) bumped to 200: http://stackoverflow.uservoice.com/pages/1722-general/suggestions/200458-add-warning-for-new-tags

Comment: On SO the FAQ actually says 250: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: D'oh; I originally checked the MSO FAQ (where it is 100): http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: "StackOverflow: You need 200 rep in order to view this motto, unless you need 250 rep, or was it 100...?"