# How to add a new tag on Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation

I want to know how to create a new tag on Stack Overflow. Where is the entrance of this function?

Please post a screenshot for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry I destroyed [your newly-created tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103680/why-can-i-create-a-new-tag-on-mso-when-i-only-have-700-reputation), but it seemed to be a duplicate of the existing [meta-tag:tag-creation] tag. :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create a Tag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4876/how-can-i-create-a-tag)

Comment: well .. how about suggesting a tag to stack community ? how much rep do i need at-least to suggest them in order to ask a question on this community related to that particular tag only.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

You need [1500 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags) on Stack Overflow to create a new tag. Unfortunately, you don't have that much yet.

If you *did have* 1500 rep, then you could create a new tag simply by adding the tag to a question. The tag will be created automatically.

Comment: well .. how about suggesting a tag to stack community ? how much rep do i need at-least to suggest them in order to ask a question on this community related to that particular tag only.

Comment: Still can't create it even though my reputation is over minimum required repuation

Comment: @Farid: I'm asssuming you have followed the guidelines at `https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags` it should work once you cross 1500. If not this could be a bug

Comment: @JoseK, exactly, I have 1500+ reputation on stackoverflow.com yet, system removes the tag once the question posted. Anyway, not a big deal ))

Answer (score 18):

You edit a question and type in a tag that doesn't exist, so long as you have the [create tag privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags).

Comment: System immediately removes my tag even though I've reputation over the threshhold necessary to create new tag