# Can I ask a question not related to any problem just to create a tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

To create a tag you need at least 1500 reputation and need to ask or edit a question and add the new tag to your question, this is clear.

https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags

like JoseK said in this post: [How to add a new tag on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103676/how-to-add-a-new-tag-on-stack-overflow)

> You need 1500 reputation on Stack Overflow to create a new tag.
>   Unfortunately, you don't have that much yet.
>
> If you did have 1500 rep, then you could create a new tag simply by
>   adding the tag to a question. The tag will be created automatically.

Now I want to create a tag, so I want to ask a question which is not related to any problem. Is that possible, or this is not possible and a bad idea?

Or is there any other way to create a tag?

Any clarification about this answer here also?

[Can we please have the [foo] tag on our site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146949/can-we-please-have-the-foo-tag-on-our-site?answertab=oldest#tab-top)

like what they say here:

> **If you have enough reputation to create the tag, and if you think
>   there is a clear need for a tag, go ahead and create it yourself**. If
>   the new tag causes controversy, you can always come back to your
>   site's meta to ask the community to judge it.

So is there another way to create a tag, which I don't know of, or what does this mean?

Comment: why this downvote? can you explain to me why?

Comment: Surely either there is an existing question that needs the tag or you have a question that needs the tag... otherwise what's the point?

Comment: Please do **not** [crosspost](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338169/can-i-ask-a-question-that-not-related-to-any-problem-just-to-create-a-tag). See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069)

Comment: Why do you want the tag in the first instance?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the tag legitimately belongs on the site, then *ask an on-topic question* where it would be applicable. If the question is well-received, you can go to the meta site and ask for the tag to be created, and give the reasons why. Or, alternately, you could earn enough rep on the site to simply create it yourself.

Asking bad questions in an attempt to accomplish something unrelated is very very likely to land you a suspension - I don't recommend it.

Answer (score 5):

In theory, yes. You can ask a bad question, put the new tag on it, and it will be created.

However, your bad question will almost certainly be closed before gaining any answers, and is likely to be downvoted. Then it will be deleted, either manually by people voting or by the Roomba. **And when it is deleted, the tag will go with it.**

If the tag truly belongs on the site, it applies to some questions on the site. Add it to some questions that exist; this will also create it. If it doesn't apply to any existing question, there's no reason to try to create it.

Comment: your answer is really clear now thank you so much i appreciated :)

Comment: Note, tags that are no longer attached to any _visible_ questions are automatically culled, so @YoucefLaidani I really don't recommend trying that.

Answer (score 2):

> So I want to ask a question that not related to any problem, is that possible or this is not and bad idea?

What is on-topic on a Stack Exchange site is defined in its respective [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); I doubt that it is possible to ask an on-topic question which is not related to any problem.

> So is there another way to create a tag, which I don't know of, or what does this mean?

No - the only way to create a tag is to add it to a (new or existing) question. I see that you have the create tag privilege on Stack Overflow, but not the edit privilege. You could *suggest* an edit to an existing question, adding the new tag. The tricky part is convincing the reviewers that this new tag adds enough value to warrant an edit.

Comment: to use it with other users this is why!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in above answers don't go that way to ask a illegitimate question just to create a tag wait for the time when you really want to ask the question.

But there is an another way to create tag without asking the question you can retag a question by editing the question in which you feel like that question is suitable for the topic on which you want to create your tag but the tag will only be created if your edit is successfully implemented.

For convincing part you can mention in your edit summary why this new tag helps to expand the focus of topic.

After your new tag is created you can choose improve tag info to give your tag details and a tag wiki to help understand other users that what is the use of this tag.

[image]