# How to add details to a tag?

Tags: support, tags, tag-wiki

I am going to add a new tag, and it is something that does not have lots of users, and I also need to write details for the tag and what that tag is about, I know how to add a new tag (by [this source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103676/how-to-add-a-new-tag-on-stack-overflow)), but is it possible for me to add details for the added tag?

The tag is the name of a service/product, and it does not have many users *(right now it just has 1 question)* but it will have more questions in the future.

But I also need to define what is that tag (I saw tags have descriptions, for example the [sku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sku) tag).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Once the tag is created, you'll be able to suggest a *tag excerpt* and a *tag wiki*. Just click on the tag, and follow the 'help us create it' link on the next page.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, then first I need to add the tag. Is it okay if I make a tag for our product? I mean we do not have lots of users... maybe just 5-10 questions a month

Comment: I just added the tag, but it does not show me the "help us to creat it" ! 
here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/befrest

Comment: That page might be cached, please wait a few minutes.

Comment: and here is one question that a user asked about something and had problem about befrest 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33773763/could-not-normalize-path-in-bintrayupload

Comment: ohh! Yes, maybe I should wait until the user accept my edit. I added the befrest tag to his question

Comment: You should only add the tag if the question is *about* your product/library. Is it really the source of the OP's problem?

Comment: Yes, I searched for the product name on StackOverflow and found a user used that and tried to add the tag to the question, and Stack Overflow asked me to add the tag, I accepted

Comment: Well, to me, that question you linked doesn't seem to *depend* on befrest; it merely *contains* it. I can imagine the same problem arises if the user users another library than befrest.

Comment: Yeah! From that view you are right. The problem that he has is from other things, not the befrest tag... I will remove that tag from that edit

Comment: Don't worry, there might be future questions which do deserve the befrest tag.

Comment: Thank you so much, I also saw you edited the question on StackOverflow :)
 Maybe we can simulate a user problem to be able to add the tag for the first time.