# How can I create a synonym for a tag?

Tags: support, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are tag synonyms? How do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work)

How can I create  synonyms for a tag in stack overflow.Anyone please suggest a way.Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4876/how-can-i-create-a-tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the tag for which you want to create a synonym you'll see the following:

> Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

To create one when you have satisfied the required criteria you can visit the `http://stackoverflow.com/tags/<tag-name>/synonyms` link.

For example if you want to create a synonym for javascript you'd go to `http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/synonyms`.

Also this link is visible in the `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/<tag-name>` page.[image]

Answer (score 2):

As stated on the [privileges page](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges), you'll need 2500 reputation points to
[suggest and vote on tag synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/suggest-tag-synonyms). The system works on voting. So you can suggest a synonym and then it is subject to comunity voting -

> #### How do synonyms get approved?
>
> When a tag synonym reaches a vote score of 4, it is accepted and
> becomes active. If a tag synonym reaches a vote score of -2 it is
> deleted.

Comment: You may also want to note that an answer score of 5 for the tag is required as well.

Comment: @jos - thanks! I needed something to pad this answer with ;)

Comment: Thanks for the information.