# Tag creation request

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation

How to create a tag for a very new and specific topic, which have a really small number of followers (all of them with low reputation on stackoverflow) in the optic of having a growing community that help each others by answering questions related to the topic ( inexistant in stackoverflow for the moment ) ?

Comment: What's the tag?

Comment: Tags are not created in the absence of questions. They are created when there is a sufficient number of questions about a topic. So have your users ask good questions. Then we'll happily add the tag. P.s. keep in mind that this is not your average support forum. We have quality guidelines for posts.

Comment: You could ask your own question regarding the tool (which you can later answer yourself) and then request for a tag to be created for it. But depending on the tool, people may not be willing to create your tag

Comment: @musefan It's usually a matter of there being a couple of genuine, appropriate questions on the topic. And self-answered questions might be a way to get things started, but then the OP has to take really good care of asking both good questions and posting good answers. A good answer to a bad question will not save the post.

Comment: @Bart: Of course, all question and answers should be of the upmost highest quality... comments however, well no one gives a f*** about them!!!

Comment: [Right.....](http://i.imgur.com/smm4RYY.gif) @musefan.

Comment: I can't unfortunately as I have a low reputation.
I'm actually far from the 1500 required.
The tag I want to create is "lightning_workbench" It is a tool aiming at creating DSMLs based on Alloy. ( but It would be inappropriate to flood the Alloy tag with question related to this tool)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4876/how-can-i-create-a-tag) post.  Tags get created when there's a clear need for them, not the other way around.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the answer, I already saw this post, but well, what if all of the person interested in the use of such a tag don't have enough reputation on stackoverflow ?

The tool is really specific , and only a short population at this very moment is interested in such a tag.
I intended to use stackoverflow as a way to grow a little community around the questions related to the tool.

But I guess it's not appropriate ...

Comment: @faboul that is appropriate use - others have done it (and others have tried and failed too).  the idea is the questions come first, then the tag.  Just have people ask a couple of questions and once there are enough (quality posts) someone will probably be happy to create the tag.

Comment: If it's a language you wrote, which was your original question, maybe you could have your own messageboard?  I use a popular 3rd party tool for C# development by a company called Infragistics, yet there's no Infragistics tag here.  So I go to their messageboard, where they have developers ready to answer questions.

Comment: I could indeed, I will need to think of this . anyway thanks for your useful feedback ;)

Comment: @JohnnyBones That statement appears to be false: [tag:infragistics]. There is probably also a tag for the specific tool that you use; I can't say because you didn't mention the name of it.

Comment: I'm sure there's no tag because I'm the creator of this tool. But anyway, thanks for your concern, I'll find another solution.

Answer (score 2):

When someone with enough reputation asks a question about your tool they can create a tag to go with it. That's the way they get created. If a tag has no questions it will be removed by the system.

Comment: I got those points, but I was thinking that there was ,aybe an "hidden" way to create tag when they are actually needed.

Anyway, I guess the only solution is to find someone with the required reputation willing to create the tag ;) or to grow myself such a reputation but i guess it can take quite a long time X.x